# Angular controller pattern

Tags: angularjs

Question about controller design in angular.  A simple example:

Consider an application as follows:
- two controllers, one that manages the header of the webpage and one for the main body
- a service, which provides data to both controllers.

In the header of the page, I show a count of the number of elements in the body.  Think of it like the classic email inbox: the "inbox" label on the top tells you how many unread messages you have, with the messages listed in the body.

If the body needs to modify the data (say delete one of those messages), it calls the service to do so, which then does an $emit() to tell the header controller it needs to reload the count.

So my pattern for the header controller is as follows:

```
Service.getCount().then(function(data) {
    $scope.paymentCount=data;
     });

$rootScope.$on('accountDetailUpdated', function() {
    Service.getCount().then(function(data) {
            $scope.paymentCount=data;
    });                     
});
```

In reality, the app is more complicated; there are multiple scope variables in the header that need to loaded and updated

My question: the pattern of the header controller seems redundant.  I have to a) load and b) watch, and in both cases the code is very similar.  Is there a cleaner way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a very interesting read about your problem there. http://blog.ponyfoo.com/2014/02/14/angle-brackets-rifle-scopes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to define a service that would be referred both by header controller and main body controller. difference will be that ur service will not only provide methods but also provide an object literal for example inbox .

and then in ur header controller u will refer inbox object 
and same in ur body controller u will refer inbox object
and on deleting item ur service will update inbox object .

using this way u dont need to emit neither broadcast. and all ur changes will be updated automatically

for example :

**Service**

```
 var _inbox={items: 20;  }

getInstance = function () {
 return _inbox; }

 deleteItems = function () {
 _inbox.items --;   }
```

Header Controller (inject inboxservice)

```
var header = inboxservice.getInstance();
//define other methods  depend on need
$scope.header= header;
```

Header HTML

```
<span >{{header.items}} </span> //it will show 20 at start
```

Body Controller (inject inbox service)

```
var body = inboxservice.getInstance();
 //define other methods  depend on need
$scope.body=body;
```

Body HTML

```
<a> <delete Item > //it will call delete method of inbox service </a>
```

as service will update inbox items length you will get change in Header HTML . for example 20 to 19 on first delete .

Comment: Doh - getting lost in angular made me forget some basics about javascript... Thanks!